# Django Rest Framework Returns old Data after post_save Signal

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have game,genre and producer tables. User creates new games through admin panel. After user creates a new game i need to do something but i have a problem. After new game has been created django sends signal and runs game_changed method. Problem is when i send get request to /api/game/ (Django rest framework endpoint) after i got signal of new game has been created response doesn't have this new model. More interesting is first i get count of game table through Game.objects.count i get 3 (correct) after that i send get request to game endpoint and response has 2 games. What causes this?

Models:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    producer=models.ForeignKey("Producer",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    genres=models.ManyToManyField("Genre")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Producer(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Genre(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Signals:

```
from django.db.models import signals
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Game

@receiver(signals.post_save,sender=Game)
def game_changed(sender,**kwargs):
    print(Game.objects.count())#Returns 3
    import requests
    url="http://localhost:8000/api/game/"
    response=requests.get(url)
    print(response.json())# returns 2 games instead of 3
```

Views:

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ReadOnlyModelViewSet
from .serializers import GenreSerializer,GameSerializer,ProducerSerializer
from .models import Genre,Game,Producer

class GenreViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset=Genre.objects.all()
    serializer_class=GenreSerializer
    search_fields=("name",)

class GameViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset=Game.objects.all()
    serializer_class=GameSerializer
    filterset_fields=("genres","producer")
    search_fields=("name",)

class ProducerViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset=Producer.objects.all()
    serializer_class=ProducerSerializer
    search_fields=("name",)
```

Comment: I would like to ask the question, why make a request to your own server from itself? It really doesn't make sense you can simply import the relevant things and get that data yourself. Next what database are you using and is `DEBUG = True` in the settings?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I am using mysql and debug is true. When user adds a new game i wanna send a message to another application through rabbitmq. When that application receives the message it needs to get all games through api. That's why i send api call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what's occuring here is a transaction isolation timing issue. While the transaction has been committed the database hasn't gotten to the point where it's readable. You can configure the transaction isolation level in your [database settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/). Or you can use [`transaction.on_commit`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit).

I'd probably reach for `transaction.on_commit` as modifying your transaction isolation level can have wide reaching effects.

Comment: But when i run Game.objects.all() i can get all data in table.

Comment: @name this might really be the issue, with `DEBUG = True` each request is served by a different thread, meaning there is a new connection to the database. if you have set some settings for transactions this might be the issue. Moving forward I repeat my comment above why make a request from the server to itself? Just import the serializer and use it in the signal if you want to.

Comment: That specific db connection session may be able to read the data that was committed in an earlier transaction. Whereas an API call or celery task would have a new session and the database may not have the transaction in a readable state for that connection. I'd suggest reading more about MySQL's isolation levels to determine that.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat actually i need to make api call from another application (flask) when i receive this signal. i use rabbitmq for this.

Comment: I've used this pattern in my own application for that exact case you're describing @name.

Comment: @schillingt i will try on_commit and keep you posted.

Comment: I added transaction.on_commit() listener to game_chaned method and sent api call when transaction committed. Looks like it works. Thanks so much for your help @schillingt

Comment: I would like to thank you for your help too @AbdulAzizBarkat